# Railo Query of Query returning incorrect results

Tags: coldfusion, railo, qoq

I'm running the following two statements:

First is A) which does what it needs to do and works:

```
SELECT
  itemColumn
 ,valueColumn
 ,label
 FROM
 rstCombinedChartData

 UNION ALL

 SELECT
 itemColumn
 ,CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn
 ,label
 FROM
 rstChartData
```

This gives me the following results:

[image]

Next I need to take these results and get back total of itemcolumn for each value in this case yes and no i.e.

```
i.e.
Yes 200
No 400
```

B) This is the query I have for to achieve this:

```
SELECT
itemColumn
,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
,label
FROM
rstCombinedChartData (this is above result set)
GROUP BY
label
,itemColumn
ORDER BY
label DESC
,itemColumn DESC
```

However, I get the following result which is not correct:

[image]

Whats going on here with query B it should be yes = x and no = x, instead I'm getting false and all the totals?

CF function:

```
    <cffunction name="getAverageChartData" hint="I return the data required to render an average chart." returntype="array" output="false">
        <cfargument name="surveyList" hint="I am a record set of Surveys." required="true" type="query" />
        <cfargument name="filter" hint="I am the optional filter which is to be applied to all results." required="false" default="" type="string" />

        <cfset var local=structNew() />

        <cfset var rstChartData="" />
        <cfset var rstChartDataTotal="" />
        <cfset var rstCombinedChartData=queryNew("itemColumn,valueColumn,label","varchar,integer,varchar") />

        <cfset local.objQuestion=objQuestionService.get(arguments.surveyList.question_ID[1]) />
        <cfset local.intQuestionTypeID = local.objQuestion.getTypeID() />

        <cfset local.strSubQuestionList=local.objQuestion.getAnswer() />
        <cfset local.strPossibleAnswerList=local.objQuestion.getPossibleAnswer() />

        <cfset local.arrChartDataResult=arrayNew(1) />

<!--- loop over each school's survey --->
        <cfloop query="arguments.surveyList">
            <cfset local.arrChartData = getChartData(arguments.surveyList.survey_id, arguments.surveyList.question_id, arguments.filter) />

<!--- loop over each sub question and append (union) it to a running total --->
            <cfloop array="#local.arrChartData#" index="rstChartData">
                <cfquery name="rstCombinedChartData" dbtype="query">
                    SELECT
                         itemColumn
                        ,valueColumn
                        ,label
                    FROM
                        rstCombinedChartData

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                         itemColumn
                        ,CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn
                        ,label
                    FROM
                        rstChartData
                </cfquery>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>


<!--- get the totals for each itemColumn --->
            <cfquery name="rstChartDataTotal" dbtype="query">
                SELECT
                     itemColumn
                    ,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
                    ,label
                FROM
                    rstCombinedChartData
                GROUP BY
                     label
                    ,itemColumn
                ORDER BY
                     label DESC
                    ,itemColumn DESC
            </cfquery>
```

**OK - Major UPDATE**

I have no idea why but I added this line in by mistake:

```
<cfset querySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "1") />
```

All of a sudden the query started to work in Railo! Ok now I have one extra result  that makes no sense "1" but WTF! It seems that Railo does not like all yes, no answers I put something else into the mix and it starts to tread it correctly again as varchars like it should.

anyone know whats going on here? I have tired casting in sql as varchar but this does not work only at the CF level does something happen.

[image]

If i take out the line:

```
<cfset querySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "1") />
```

it goes back to:

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to be a MySQL question, as the query you're working on is a query-on-query, not a DB query.  Can you do me a favour? JSONify your recordset `rstCombinedChartData` and post it here? I'll have a play around. Might pay to de-tag your question of "SQL" and "MySQL" as CFML's dialect of SQL is rather different/limited compared to standard SQL dialects.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try casting your itemColumn as varchar in your q of q.

Comment: @Adam Cameron only thing I have noticed it that it works if the itemColumn is 'boy' 'girl'. but the values 'yes' 'no' do something strange to the query.

Comment: @AdamCameron I have updated the question with the full function in CFML

Comment: Yeah, it'll be some CFML boolean weirdness. That's why I was actual the actual *data* (not so much "more code") so I can have a look here. I'm too lazy to type in "Yes,33", "No,45" etc for 18 rows to replicate the data in your screen cap ;-)

Comment: Are you required to use a Query of Queries?  Any reason you can't just do by hitting the database directly??

Comment: 1) Which version of Railo? 2) Which version of MySQL, and Which driver are you using in the original database query? 3) What are the data types of the three columns involved?

Comment: @Leigh I thinks its a Railo issue (running version Railo 4.0.4.001 final) I run the same code on ACF 9 and it works!

Comment: @User7 - What about my other two questions? Like others, I cannot reproduce your issue either. We need more information about your environment.

Comment: @Leigh I have updated the question got some strange results. mysql version is 5. the data types should be as follows itemColumn - varchar, valueColumn = int label = varchar

Comment: @User7 - just to clarify, we can see that those are the data types for the `rstCombinedChartData` query but what about the data types from the `getChartData` function call? I assume that is returning an array of resultsets from the actual database query. Just wanted clarification on the data types in the database, not the in memory ColdFusion query.

Comment: In the DB data type is LONGTEXT for itemColumn, label and INT(11) for valueColumn

Comment: I'm curious why you had to CAST the valueColumn as an integer in this line `CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn` when it is already an integer?  Have you tried casting your `itemColumn` as a Char in the same SQL statement?

Comment: Just a note, in MySQL you cannot cast to VARCHAR. In MySQL you use CHAR.

Answer (score 3):

*From the comments* - I am curious why you had to CAST the `valueColumn` as an integer in the line `CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn` when it is already an integer?

You should try casting your `itemColumn` as a char in the same SQL statement. Note: in MySQL you cannot cast to VARCHAR. In MySQL you must use CHAR.  Something like `CAST(itemColumn AS CHAR) AS itemColumn`.

*The rest of this is not really an answer but was too long for a comment*

I created a self-contained repro based on the data that you shared but I cannot get it to fail. Your query works correctly for me in ACF and Railo. Copy the code below and paste it into [cflive.net](http://cflive.net/).

```
<cftry>
<cfset rstCombinedChartData = QueryNew("itemColumn,valueColumn,label","varchar,integer,varchar") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 33) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 45) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 72) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 66) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 42) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 38) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 64) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 83) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 65) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 43) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "Yes") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(rstCombinedChartData) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "itemColumn", "No") />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "valueColumn", 0) />
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(rstCombinedChartData, "label", "") />
<cfquery name="rstChartDataTotal" dbtype="query">
    SELECT
        itemColumn
        ,SUM(valueColumn) AS valueColumn
        ,label
    FROM
        rstCombinedChartData
    GROUP BY
        label
        ,itemColumn
    ORDER BY
        label DESC
        ,itemColumn DESC
</cfquery>
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <div>
            <cfoutput query="rstChartDataTotal">
            <p>#rstChartDataTotal.itemColumn# - #rstChartDataTotal.valueColumn#</p>
            </cfoutput>
            <cfdump var="#rstCombinedChartData#" label="rstCombinedChartData" />
            <hr />
            <cfdump var="#rstChartDataTotal#" label="rstChartDataTotal" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

You can see in the `cfdump` results of `rstChartDataTotal` that Railo maintains the `itemColumn` as a varchar and still displays "yes" or "no".

[image: Railo dump]

In Adobe ColdFusion it changes the `itemColumn` to a boolean and displays as "true" or "false".

[image: ACF dump]

I believe that anomaly is only coming from the output generated at [cflive.net](http://cflive.net/), but in both cases the query still ran and correctly calculated the results of both columns?

Comment: I ran your code and yes that worked, but my query still does not so it has to be an issues with the way CF is changing it. The funny thing is that on ACF my code works and not on Railo

Comment: @User7 - This is an issue where you really need to post a [self-contained](http://www.sscce.org/) repro case. Since no one has been able to duplicate your issue, there is obviously *something* different in your code (possibly environment). However, it is extremely difficult to pinpoint since we cannot see the code - or the data - for most of the functions you are using. (A dump/serialize of *all* `local` values before the problematic QoQ loop would help). If you post a complete sample, I think you will have a much better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a scoping/ reference issue;

Change:

```
<cfquery name="rstCombinedChartData" dbtype="query">
```

Into

```
<cfquery name="local.q" dbtype="query">
```

Then after the QoQ, at the end of the local.arrChartData loop, set it back to the rstCombinedChartData variable;

```
        <cfloop array="#local.arrChartData#" index="rstChartData">
            <cfquery name="local.q" dbtype="query">
                SELECT
                     itemColumn
                    ,valueColumn
                    ,label
                FROM
                    rstCombinedChartData

                UNION ALL

                SELECT
                     itemColumn
                    ,CAST(valueColumn AS INTEGER) AS valueColumn
                    ,label
                FROM
                    rstChartData
            </cfquery>
            <cfset rstCombinedChartData = local.q />
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
```

This should make sure all pointers/ references are set correctly.

Comment: No joy with that sorry. same results given

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT UNIQUE itemColumn
      , SUM( SELECT valueColumn 
             FROM   rstCombinedChartData 
             WHERE itemColumn = "yes") as YES
      , SUM ( SELECT valueColumn 
             FROM   rstCombinedChartData 
             WHERE  itemColumn = "no") as NO
      , label;
```

Comment: I cannot use this sorry, itemColumn can be more than yes or no.

Comment: No problem, you can use values other than yes or no here. Because UNIQUE key word just will not allow you to insert duplicate values. Try this and and tell me what output you are getting. But am not forcing you to do this. okay?